# Categorizing Markers Android Google Maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, markers

it is possible to categorize markers? Because i want to make a check box when malls is checked, all markers with mall type should be set to visible, I have a code but it occurs problem. Here it is

```
Marker malls = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(14.584149, 120.981499))
    .title("Luneta Park"))
    .setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.second));
```

Errors displays> Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Marker. ANY help will be aprreciated, advance thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is where the error occurs? Post your logcat

Comment: yygyt no logcat detected because i cant run the app because it has an error

Comment: I cant figure this out until this time, by the way thanks for helping